# how to prevent field update multiple times in workflow

Tags: workflow, configuration

I have a picklist and date fields on custom object `object__c`

- `date__c` - field
- `picklist__c` - field

I am updating `date__c` field with date when `picklist__c` is updated from workflow on below criteria.

```
AND(
    ISNEW(),
    NOT(ISPICKVAL(picklist__c,''))
)
|| ISCHANGED(Picklist__c).
```

In this criteria, when ever the picklist is changed, then date is updated.

I am trying to write logic, such that date field populated when the picklist is updated and cannot be changed once it is populated. Can someone help me write the logic.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to populate `date__c` field only when `picklist__c` value is set for the first time. This should do it:

```
AND(
 OR(
  ISCHANGED(Picklist__c),
  ISNEW()
 ),
 NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT(picklist__c))),
 ISBLANK(date__c)
)
```